# Is there a way to sync up live audio and live video using Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, audio, synchronization

I am trying to write a bit of code to create a 2 person live chat application using Python 3. The code is working in the sense of having live audio and live video, (as tested by running the server and 2 clients on the same device), with the Client-Side code running most of the logic and running the camera and audio feeds to send through the server, (which also works as a form of handshake between the 2 clients with little logic aside from if a client sends video and/or audio to send it to the other client), to have the client-side code to get the audio and video to play.

*fair warning, this code is a bit messy and is not optimized for fast performance*

**Client-Side Code:**

```
import cv2
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM
from imutils.video import WebcamVideoStream
import pyaudio
from array import array
from threading import Thread
import numpy as np
import zlib
import struct

HOST = input("Enter Server IP\n")
PORT_VIDEO = 3000
PORT_AUDIO = 4000

BufferSize = 4096
CHUNK=1024
lnF = 640*480*3
FORMAT=pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS=2
RATE=44100

def SendAudio():
    while True:
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        dataChunk = array('h', data)
        vol = max(dataChunk)
        clientAudioSocket.sendall(data)

def RecieveAudio():
    while True:
        data = recvallAudio(BufferSize)
        stream.write(data)

def recvallAudio(size):
    databytes = b''
    while len(databytes) != size:
        to_read = size - len(databytes)
        if to_read > (4 * CHUNK):
            databytes += clientAudioSocket.recv(4 * CHUNK)
        else:
            databytes += clientAudioSocket.recv(to_read)
    return databytes

def SendFrame():
    while True:
        try:
            frame = wvs.read()
            cv2_im = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480))
            frame = np.array(frame, dtype = np.uint8).reshape(1, lnF)
            jpg_as_text = bytearray(frame)

            databytes = zlib.compress(jpg_as_text, 9)
            length = struct.pack('!I', len(databytes))
            bytesToBeSend = b''
            clientVideoSocket.sendall(length)
            while len(databytes) > 0:
                if (5000 * CHUNK) <= len(databytes):
                    bytesToBeSend = databytes[:(5000 * CHUNK)]
                    databytes = databytes[(5000 * CHUNK):]
                    clientVideoSocket.sendall(bytesToBeSend)
                else:
                    bytesToBeSend = databytes
                    clientVideoSocket.sendall(bytesToBeSend)
                    databytes = b''
            # ~ print("##### Data Sent!! #####")
        except:
            continue


def RecieveFrame():
    while True:
        try:
            lengthbuf = recvallVideo(4)
            length, = struct.unpack('!I', lengthbuf)
            databytes = recvallVideo(length)
            img = zlib.decompress(databytes)
            if len(databytes) == length:
                # ~ print("Recieving Media..")
                # ~ print("Image Frame Size:- {}".format(len(img)))
                img = np.array(list(img))
                img = np.array(img, dtype = np.uint8).reshape(480, 640, 3)
                cv2.imshow("Stream", img)
                if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            else:
                print("Data CORRUPTED")
        except:
            continue


def recvallVideo(size):
    databytes = b''
    while len(databytes) != size:
        to_read = size - len(databytes)
        if to_read > (5000 * CHUNK):
            databytes += clientVideoSocket.recv(5000 * CHUNK)
        else:
            databytes += clientVideoSocket.recv(to_read)
    return databytes



clientVideoSocket = socket(family=AF_INET, type=SOCK_STREAM)
clientVideoSocket.connect((HOST, PORT_VIDEO))
wvs = WebcamVideoStream(0).start()

clientAudioSocket = socket(family=AF_INET, type=SOCK_STREAM)
clientAudioSocket.connect((HOST, PORT_AUDIO))

audio=pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream=audio.open(format=FORMAT,channels=CHANNELS, rate=RATE, input=True, output = True,frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

initiation = clientVideoSocket.recv(5).decode()

if initiation == "start":
    SendFrameThread = Thread(target=SendFrame).start()
    SendAudioThread = Thread(target=SendAudio).start()
    RecieveFrameThread = Thread(target=RecieveFrame).start()
    RecieveAudioThread = Thread(target=RecieveAudio).start()
```

**Server-Side Code:**

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM
from threading import Thread
import struct

HOST = input("Enter Host IP\n")
PORT_VIDEO = 3000
PORT_AUDIO = 4000
lnF = 640*480*3
CHUNK = 1024
BufferSize = 4096
addressesAudio = {}
addresses = {}
threads = {}

def ConnectionsVideo():
    while True:
        try:
            clientVideo, addr = serverVideo.accept()
            print("{} is connected!!".format(addr))
            addresses[clientVideo] = addr
            if len(addresses) > 1:
                for sockets in addresses:
                    if sockets not in threads:
                        threads[sockets] = True
                        sockets.send(("start").encode())
                        Thread(target=ClientConnectionVideo, args=(sockets, )).start()
            else:
                continue
        except:
            continue

def ConnectionsSound():
    while True:
        try:
            clientAudio, addr = serverAudio.accept()
            print("{} is connected!!".format(addr))
            addressesAudio[clientAudio] = addr
            Thread(target=ClientConnectionSound, args=(clientAudio, )).start()
        except:
            continue

def ClientConnectionVideo(clientVideo):
    while True:
        try:
            lengthbuf = recvall(clientVideo, 4)
            length, = struct.unpack('!I', lengthbuf)
            recvall(clientVideo, length)
        except:
            continue

def ClientConnectionSound(clientAudio):
    while True:
        try:
            data = clientAudio.recv(BufferSize)
            broadcastSound(clientAudio, data)
        except:
            continue

def recvall(clientVideo, BufferSize):
        databytes = b''
        i = 0
        while i != BufferSize:
            to_read = BufferSize - i
            if to_read > (1000 * CHUNK):
                databytes = clientVideo.recv(1000 * CHUNK)
                i += len(databytes)
                broadcastVideo(clientVideo, databytes)
            else:
                if BufferSize == 4:
                    databytes += clientVideo.recv(to_read)
                else:
                    databytes = clientVideo.recv(to_read)
                i += len(databytes)
                if BufferSize != 4:
                    broadcastVideo(clientVideo, databytes)
        # ~ print("YES!!!!!!!!!" if i == BufferSize else "NO!!!!!!!!!!!!")
        if BufferSize == 4:
            broadcastVideo(clientVideo, databytes)
            return databytes

def broadcastVideo(clientSocket, data_to_be_sent):
    for clientVideo in addresses:
        if clientVideo != clientSocket:
            clientVideo.sendall(data_to_be_sent)

def broadcastSound(clientSocket, data_to_be_sent):
    for clientAudio in addressesAudio:
        if clientAudio != clientSocket:
            clientAudio.sendall(data_to_be_sent)

serverVideo = socket(family=AF_INET, type=SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    serverVideo.bind((HOST, PORT_VIDEO))
except OSError:
    print("Server Busy")

serverAudio = socket(family=AF_INET, type=SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    serverAudio.bind((HOST, PORT_AUDIO))
except OSError:
    print("Server Busy")

serverAudio.listen(2)
print("Waiting for audio connection..")
AcceptThreadAudio = Thread(target=ConnectionsSound)
AcceptThreadAudio.start()


serverVideo.listen(2)
print("Waiting for video connection..")
AcceptThreadVideo = Thread(target=ConnectionsVideo)
AcceptThreadVideo.start()
AcceptThreadVideo.join()
serverVideo.close()
```

Both of these codes are what I have put together in a bit longer of time than I would have liked, but I noticed when doing a bit of testing with these codes that the audio and video were off by anywhere between 3 and 7 seconds. I tried a bit of troubleshooting but couldn't find any issues with the code, aside from the fact that it looks like a kid threw it all together. I am fine with importing a new Python package, but I would prefer to use the Python Packages that I already have in place. Keep in mind I am thinking about eventually converting both the codes into separate .exe files to allow for easy access to send the codes to individual people.

Comment: to reduce lag make the buffer smaller yet I see your buffers are already small so the lag is coming from elsewhere ...  as a programming challenge I commend you however if your goal is the achieve the best quality live audio/video I would strive to avoid having a server sit in the middle between two parties ... WebRTC is a modern way to create a video chat which directly connects the two people which avoids any server in the middle